# How to cache values from db just after deploy on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I want to cache some values from db after deploy to heroku, but I can't work with db in initializers or in confir.after_initialize, because I have error:

```
Mysql::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Code example:

```
Rails.cache.fetch("users_count") do
   User.where(:urank => URank.user).count
end
```

Doesn't work for me too:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Thank you!

P.S. I know, that I can write some def in users model file, and call it each time, but I just want to know, how how to work with db on start up.

Comment: I guess Heroku wants you to use 'pg' ( Postgres ). I might be wrong but this what they ask you to use.

Comment: OK, This might help https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: This seems like a configuration issue within your app, which makes it try to use a local database by default when it should use a config variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
But:
1)It works fine with mysql
2)I wrote about initialize_on_precompile (And as I know it is for rails3 option)
3)Its ok with database.yml file, If I don't work with database in initializers